# Initializing windows server 2019 for hosting multiple website multiple domain names and single IP

Tags: web-hosting, static-ip, dns-server, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I want to set up a virtual machine to host windows server 2019 to host multiple websites in IIS 10. Each website can be reached with a domain name for example:

- www.website1.com
- www.website2.com
- www.website3.com

This server just has these IPs:

- The single global static IP address we assume it **205.100.100.100**
- The local IP address in the local network we assume it
  **192.168.1.1**

Now I want to be able to define *ns1* and *ns2* for setting in *websites DNS name servers* to locate to this server as each unique domain name locates to its own website source hosted in IIS inside the server just with **single static IP** that server has. I read about recognition of the requested website through the same IP with **HTTP Headers** but this way not working if we want using SSL. I think the solution maybe same as NAT technology and must be map request to correct internally hosted website. I don't know if this is possible but I saw Hosting companies don't use a new static IP for each new website. I just want to do the same things. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Don't host your own DNS, especially if you are new to DNS. Use the DNS service provided by your registrar, or a third party DNS service.

Comment: Like the other comment indicated, use an external DNS service, and map all domain names to the external IP address of your server (205.100.100.100). On IIS side, binding the different sites to the same IP address is OK, because IIS 8 and above already supports SNI for HTTPS https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability When in doubt, learn the technical details behind https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for answers. Actually, I got a VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) service on an OpenStack service provider, so I have own networks and machines and no provider to obtain DNS service. In addition, I try to learn beside initializing this server. Is your advice to use the third party yet or is a good start point to host my DNS?

Comment: @LexLi Thanks so much. I'll study those links you mentioned and will share the result.